# Place :hover at end for some element's selector in LESS

Tags: css, less

It seems there's something unseen in LESS to me. I expect something like this in CSS:

```
.animate.fade-in, .animate-hover.fade-in:hover {
  animation-name: fade-in;
}
```

my LESS is :

```
.animate, .animate-hover:hover {
  &.fade-in {
    animation-name: fade-in;
  }
}
```

But what I get is :

```
.animate.fade-in, .animate-hover:hover.fade-in {
  animation-name: fade-in;
}
```

`:hover`'s place is not true in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky situation, mainly because it seems to be a case where LESS is MORE. You could, instead of repeating `.animate`, repeat the `.fade-in` like so:

**LESS**

```
.animate {
   &.fade-in, &-hover.fade-in:hover {
      animation-name: fade-in;
  }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.animate.fade-in,
.animate-hover.fade-in:hover {
  animation-name: fade-in;
}
```

**But the LESS input looks suspiciously more complicated and nearly just as long as just doing it straight as the expected css output.** So it may be best to just do that... unless you are using this as a foundation for building a mixin to do various animations this way, something like so:

```
.nameAnimation(@name) {
    .animate {
        &.@{name}, &-hover.@{name}:hover {
          animation-name: @name;
      }
    }
}

.nameAnimation(fade-in);
.nameAnimation(fade-out);
.nameAnimation(whaaa);
```

Comment: Good solution to write less. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.animate, .animate-hover {
    &.fade-in, &.fade-in:hover {
        animation-name: fade-in;
    }
}
```

I'll be honest, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it is the first solution I thought of off when I saw the question. I will say, however, that if I were in your situation, this is probably what I would do.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it is the solution I thought of off the top of my head.

Comment: I believe this will generate 2x2=4 selectors (all possible combinations)

Comment: @Mohebifar what is not true? Is there anything that I can change in my answer to make it more accurate?

Comment: It makes :
.animate.fade-in, .animate.fade-in:hover, .animate-hover.fade-in, .animate-hover.fade-in:hover {
    animation-name: fade-in;
}

Comment: @Mohebifar Oh, I see. ScottS's answer is probably what you want to use then.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using `fade-in` as a parent selector (since `&` is a place holder for the parent selector).

This should obtain what you expect:

```
.fade-in {
  .animate&, .animate-hover&:hover {
    animation-name: fade-in;
  }
}
```